# new() method returning generic 'impl trait' value

Tags: rust

I'm new to Rust language and want to create a small game to learn it.
I would like to have a **PlayerTrait** trait that would be applied to 2 types of players : **LocalPlaye**r and **Computer**, like that :

```
struct LocalPlayer{
//...
}

struct Computer {
//...
}

trait PlayerTrait {
    fn play_turn(&self);
}

impl PlayerTrait for LocalPlayer{...}
impl PlayerTrait for Computer{...}
```

Like with java interfaces, I would then like to be able to write generic code that would do different stuff depending on if it's an AI or an actual player.

After some research in vain, my Game struct looks like that :

```
struct Game<T:PlayerTrait> {
   player1 : T,
   player2 : T
}

impl<T:PlayerTrait>  Game<T> {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Game {
            player1 : LocalPlayer::new(),
            player2 : Computer::new()
        }
    }

}
```

However, I can't instantiate a player.

My **LocalPlayer** new() method looks like that: (the **Computer**'s one is quite the same for now)

```
impl LocalPlayer{
   pub fn new() -> Self {
        LocalPlayer {
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

gives :
`` ... expected type parameter `T`, found struct `util::game::player::LocalPlayer ``

Both LocalPlayer and Computer are implementing the trait,so I don't understand why it does not compile. I've tried changing the return type for `-> impl PlayerTrait`, `-> Box<PlayerTrait>`(after lurking on different websites) and still couldn't manage to make it work. 
Sorry if it's a stupid question, am I missing something?

If it might help, while tinkering with the code I would quite often get this error too :
`... expected type 'T' parameter , found opaque type`

Answer (score 3):

`T` doesn't mean "`PlayerTrait` entity", but rather it means "**one** of the types which is `PlayerTrait`". So if one of the players appears to be a `Computer` then compiler compiles your `Game` as if it was:

```
struct Game {
   player1 : Computer,
   player2 : Computer,
}
```

If `T` would be `LocalPlayer` then both players would be compiled as them. To solve the problem, add another template type in the `Game`:

```
struct Game<T1:PlayerTrait, T2:PlayerTrait> {
   player1 : T1,
   player2 : T2,
}
```

and change the rest of the code according to these two types.
This way, you get **a separate** `Game` class according to which combinations of `PlayerTraits` appeared in your code.

It's a good enough solution, it doesn't have any performance drawbacks, because you get a separate compiled class for whatever players you have. Your program will not require a *dynamic polymorphism* as in Java, where JVM has to find an appropriate override of functions you call in run-time (which isn't too slow, but slower).

On the other hand, if you have 10000 different combinations, then you get 10000 classes for all combinations sitting in your memory.

Sometimes you might want to replicate a behavior from Java (i.e. to store an object by a reference on a trait aka Java reference on an *interface*). For this you can use

```
struct Game {
   player1 : Box<dyn PlayerTrait>,
   player2 : Box<dyn PlayerTrait>,
}
```

This will enable the dynamic polymorphism: you'll have only 1 copy of the compiled class, behavior of players is determined in run-time (a bit slower), both player objects are stored on the heap.

Comment: Had to use the 'java-like' version, but it worked ! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Rust traits are not exactly like the interfaces in java.
Here the problem is you are requiring a type T that implements PlayerTrait but you are giving 2 different types to it while creating.

T must correspond to a concrete type in the end of the day.
In your case LocalComputer and Computerare two different types.

While compiling the compiler generates every possible  version of those generics.
So giving Game a Computer instead of LocalComputer is an error.

If you want to use generics similar to java interfaces you should use [trait objects](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/types/trait-object.html) rather than generics.

I also came across similar issues and ended up changing my design the problem was me misunderstanding the generics. Generics are a runtime thing as in golang interfaces it is a compile time concrete type just to help us write less code.

Also using trait object you will be paying price for extra meta data so unless you really need a runtime generic type just implement everything on a concrete type.